# Toggle effect not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

hello friends i want to use toggle on `<li>` when one `<li>` is open i want rest `<li>` get close i have tried this http://jsfiddle.net/MbTRD/1/ but its not working as i want

```
  $(function () {
        $(".flyout").hide();
        $(".flyout").siblings("span").click(function () {
            $(this).siblings(".flyout").toggle(500);
        });
    });
```

Please help thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/MbTRD/7/ should work

You had to put a `$(".flyout").hide(500);` in your function

But then you still have to check if you are clicking a open menu or not

like this

```
$(function () {
        $(".flyout").hide();
        $(".flyout").siblings("span").click(function () {
            if($(this).siblings(".flyout").is(':hidden')){
                $(".flyout").hide(500);
            }
            $(this).siblings(".flyout").toggle(500);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

consider http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
$(function () {
    $(".flyout").hide();
    $(".flyout").siblings("span").click(function () {
        $('.flyout').hide(500);                
        $(this).siblings(".flyout").toggle(500);
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't think seeing an element close and reopen is a nice user experience feature. (click again on an already opened one.) What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$(function () {
    $(".flyout").hide();
    $(".flyout").siblings("span").click(function () {
        if($(this).siblings(".flyout").is(':hidden'))
        {
            $(".flyout").hide();
            $(this).siblings(".flyout").toggle(500);
        }
    });
});
```

[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MbTRD/13/)  if you want to try it out

​

Comment: if I click on an already opened element that element will do a nice show (again.) I don't think such feature can be called a good job! What do you think?